# Genesis 6:20 Insects excluded or included?

Tags: genesis, hebrew

From Genesis 6:20:

> “Of the birds according to their kinds, and of the animals according
> to their kinds, **of every creeping thing of the ground**, according to
> its kind, two of every sort shall come in to you to keep them alive.”
> (ESV)

**crawling creature**
רֶ֥מֶשׂ (re·meś)
Noun - masculine singular construct
Strong's 7431: A reptile, any other rapidly moving animal

I don’t think a insect can be included based on the definition, but, **Q: Can insects be included in this definition by extension?**

Comment: The concepts 'animals' and 'creepers' are broad and to some extent overlap. I find it difficult to be bothered as to whether rodents and tarantulas and beetles are in the same, or different, categories. I don't think it matters, frankly.

Comment: @NigelJ Well, it does matter to my personal research; I see what you mean, but in my research on Noah’s Ark, I wanted to be certain.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Insects are included, without extension, in רמש.

The intent of the Genesis 6:20 is clear and not disputed - to be inclusive of every living thing whether flying things, animals or things that creep on the land (רמש), which includes anything else.

The Hebrew Bible uses about 8K unique words. That's relatively few. Most human speakers know 15K to 25K words, so the books of the OT, with their 419K total words are written in a style that could be called "economical" with regards to vocabulary. Tolstoy's *War and Peace* with 310K total words uses about 20k unique words. Tolstoy wrote for an educated audience in the age of printing. I conjecture that the MT was written to be accessible at varying levels of understanding - for the most part, and that's why it uses fewer unique words.

The MT of Genesis uses general terms for most living things. For example,  when the MT refers to sheep or donkey or cattle, we can't know which specific breed they were, or even if it mattered, which apparently it didn't.

MT Hebrew in fact has no special word for insect. The modern Hebrew for insect, חרק, was coined in the late nineteenth century by [Aharon Meir Maziah](https://www.geni.com/people/Aharon-Mazia/6000000029872531124).

You can't make any inferences about the MT text based on translation dictionaries, but you can ask questions about a verse based on translation dictionary entries. These dictionaries provide concise, approximate definitions only, and do not attempt to give the precise meaning of a word in each context. They are not intended to be "accurate". In fact, you can't make reliable inferences about any text from any translation dictionary, say from a French-English dictionary when reading *Les Fleurs du mal*.

The MT text is very compact with respect to most English writing. It paints with a broad brush, so the more that we try to nail down exact times of day or duration of periods of time or precise sizes, weights and types of things, the more we are distracted from the actual meaning of the text.

Comment: +1.  Good succinct answer.

Comment: @Abu So you’re saying the “BibleHub” dictionary is not as accurate?  Isn’t there a separate Hebrew word for “insect” ?

Comment: @Cork88 Thanks for your patience. After getting some sleep, I re-wrote my post with a little more patience and less bite. HTH.